# Leak of memory with PxMaterial

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, physx

I found a memory leak in my code, but i can not figure out how to fix it.

When i loop like this:

```
for (;;)
{
    physx::PxMaterial *pMaterial = pPhysic_physicsSDK->createMaterial(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    pMaterial->release();
}
```

I have memory overflow. Memory are not releasing. How to release it right?

I tried to delete it "`delete pMaterial`", but no delete access is granted.

Answer (score 0):

You're never breaking from the `for` loop. It will never stop running unless you call `break;`.

```
for (;;)
{
    physx::PxMaterial *pMaterial = pPhysic_physicsSDK->createMaterial(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    pMaterial->release();

    if(**something is satisfied**)
        break;
}
```

This would stop the memory overflow because it will eventually leave the `for` loop.

Comment: I know it. But in my code above. I suggest it have not to eat all my memory, because i release it in every loop. But it does!

Comment: Did you try dereferencing the pointer using "&" when calling delete, instead of release

Comment: try printing what pMaterial contains after you release it to make sure it is actually being released... see if that helps